# Expanding universe in string theory

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, space-expansion

The controversy over de Sitter space in string theory is well-known. But what about the plain old expanding universe? What I want is not just a field-theory approximation, but something genuinely stringy, e.g. an $S$-matrix for strings in a Friedmann-Robertson-Walker space-time. Does anything like that even exist?

Comment: As far as I understand (and my understanding is limited), it is very difficult to construct time-dependent backgrounds in string theory, so the issue is not specifically with dS.